# How to update the same column in a series of "identical" SQL tables

Tags: sql

First post... apologies if the answer's here somewhere - I've found answers to similar questions, but not this one.  And my knowledge of SQL isn't that good, although I can normally achieve what I need to.

The database has identical tables with different names, e.g. AHH_ACNT, AHL_ACNT and so on.  I can achieve what I need with a simple update statement -

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO
UPDATE AHH_ACNT
SET ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 99
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 1
SELECT * FROM AHH_ACNT
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS =1
ROLLBACK
--COMMIT


BEGIN TRAN
GO
UPDATE AHL_ACNT
SET ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 99
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 1
SELECT * FROM AHL_ACNT
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 1
ROLLBACK
--COMMIT
```

But doing that way involves 26 separate statements.  Ideally I'd write 
UPDATE %_ACNT but that wouldn't work!
Is there a way I can use a single query to do this?  Then if there's a new table I wouldn't have to create another set of rows...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you cannot update more than one table in a single update statement. One of the best things to do is to use a transaction (shown below) to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated in such a way that you don't need to worry about a partly complete operation.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE AHH_ACNT
SET ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 99
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 1

UPDATE AHL_ACNT
SET ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 99
WHERE ALLOCN_IN_PROGRESS = 1

COMMIT
```